# changing font by scrolling UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uipickerview

Is it possible to change the font of a text while scrolling down/up a UIPickerView which has all the correct names of the system fonts? So that the text changes its font to the one that is currently selected in the pickerView.

Comment: Do you want the font on the `UIPickerView` to change as the user scroll thru the list of fonts? Or do you want each name of the font displayed in the font itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a method, for UIPickerView changes the selection while scrolling up/down, in viewdidload, or method where UIPickerview get present, like

```
[uorPickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(ValueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You can set the font which has been selected from UIPickerview in ValueChanged Method like

```
-(void)ValueChanged :(UIPickerView *) sender {
      //Lets say you have UILable or UITextfield or UITextview as textView, so u can set your text like, 
      // fontArray = Array you have provided for UIPickerView datasource
      [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[fontArray objectAtIndex:[sender selectedRowInComponent:0]] size:16]]
      // make sure that fontArray has proper value of font family.
}
```

Hope this help you,

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: It helped to solve my problem thanks. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: addTarget is not available for PickerView

Answer (score 0):

You can get all system fonts and use it as your datasource

```
for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
     for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
     NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
   }
}
```

Implementing your delegate, you can create custom views for every row

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
       reusingView:(UIView *)view {

  UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;

  if (pickerLabel == nil) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
    pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [pickerLabel setFont:/*font from datasource*/];
  }

  [pickerLabel setText:[pickerDataArray objectAtIndex:row]];

  return pickerLabel;

}
```